# “NSURL” is not implicitly convertible to “URL”; did you mean to use “as” to explicitly convert? in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

[image: Error]

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply follow the `Fix-It` of the compiler?

Comment: Because the fix it results in another error, this time suggesting that you change the URL to url... which leads to another error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **swift 3.0**, the method signature for `openURL` is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(applic‌​ation, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

In method signature, `NSURL` is changed to `URL`.

Comment: still i have error :  there is no methods for openURL. it showing to change as open : url

Comment: @NithinRaghunath Are you still getting the same error? after changing  parameter type to URL from `NSURL` for `open url`.

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation). this method not supported . it getting error. It showing "fix it "replace with.   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

Comment: Then replace it. The only difference is in the method signature. It is because of swift 3.0.

Comment: I don't have any about that framework. I just knew how to correct that syntax.:)