# Facebook Login - cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'URL!'

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, authentication, swift3

[image][image: appdelegate]
Pod

- Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.23.0)
- Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.23.0)

I simply cannot go pass through this function because i cannot cast URL to URL!. I did try to cast is with ! but it wont let me through. Did i miss something during the proses ?

Cheers

PS: i did create a [github issues](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/158) for this but it seems they did not check their github repo periodically.

Comment: What does it means cast URL to URL! ????

Comment: I have no idea.. I try to cast it using as URL! But it didn't work

Comment: Man, screenshots of code... :/ Can you please include actual code in the question to make it a bit better readable? Also, why do you think you need to cast to `URL!`, which isn't even an actual type? You do know about optionals and forced unwrapping, yes? From what I see of teh SDK's documentation you should just pass a normal, non-optional URL instance, I need to see how you call those methods to understand what causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.0, the method signature for openURL is:
open url: URL

Check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739292/nsurl-is-not-implicitly-convertible-to-url-did-you-mean-to-use-as-to-expl).

Comment: now it showing "Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected type 'URL!'" i try to cast the url using as URL! but it did not work.

Comment: please post me the statement. How you tried to convert?

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.0 use this method to open a Resource idetified by a url :

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    <#code#>
}
```

Comment: did try it, but it did not work. Posted a screenshot for that in my original question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using the wrong method.

It's pretty standard stuff for using FBSDK. You should use

`func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {}`

to return

`application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)`

Typically the function should look like below in your AppDelegate-

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)

    }
```

Also, assuming that you have this, in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }
```

Also, you should be using the Facebook Swift pods-

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem until I figured out that the **URL** class used in the application method

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

was pointing to an utility class defined by me. I had to rename my URL class to APP_URL and the problem disappeared.

Ruined 2 hours of my life.